# How to prevent other roles from publishing content

Tags: users

I am new to Drupal. I am working on a website where I have 2 user roles: Site admin and editor.

The site admin has all permissions. I want the editor to only have the permission to edit content but not to publish or edit them. He can view his edited content but cannot publish them.

Different people suggested me different options, like use this module, use that module, but no body is showing me a neat and proper solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you please elaborate on your question, which modules you evaluated and why they have not been helpful?

Comment: I used one workbench moderation..which gives me the facility to add restriction to editor role but whenever an editor edit content ,edited content disaapeared from editor dashboard..which should not happen..editor should be able to edit every content in the site and have the right to edit but can not publish

Answer (score 0):

[Override Node Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) overrides this functionality and it's pretty straight forward.

> The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each
> field within the Authoring information and Publishing options field
> sets on the node form.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow),

> This module allows you to create arbitrary Workflows, and assign them
>   to Entities.
>
> Workflows are made up of workflow states. Transitions between states
>   can be allowed per role. For example, a workflow with the states
>   Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type.
>   Only users with role 'chief editor' can set Stories to the published
>   state. You can set up the Workflow to alter states from form, page,
>   comment and a special workflow tab.

with or without [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning).

> Revisioning is a module for the configuration of workflows to create,
>   moderate and publish content revisions.

Revisioning contains a slightly old tutorial on using both together on its doc pages.